# Linking files with LD

Tags: c, nasm, ld

I read this tutorial: http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/writing-a-simple-c-kernel
I tried linking the files using the likerscript that the tutorial provides. But LD gives me an error saying that it cannot read the file put out by nasm. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you executed the tutorial precisely as shown, then the problem is most likely here:

```
nasm -f aout kernel_start.asm -o ks.o
```

This produces an object file in the thoroughly obsolete *a.out* format.  You're probably working through the tutorial on either a Windows or a Linux host system; the linkers that come with these systems expect object files in PECOFF and ELF format, respectively.  There is probably another thing you can put after the `-f` in the above command that will make `nasm` produce the correct format.

Alternatively, learn to write AT&T assembly language instead.  Then you can make an object file out of your `.asm` file with `gcc -c` just like the C source code, and you will automatically get the right format.  The AT&T equivalent of the trivial startup file you have in that tutorial would be

```
    .text
    .globl start
start:
    call k_main
    cli
    hlt
```

Take note also that I removed the leading underscore from the `call` instruction's argument.  That underscore is only appropriate if the C code is compiled to an *a.out*-format object file, which (we suspect) it isn't.

Comment: I am still curious about what I can put after the -f to change the format to the one gcc wants.

Comment: There should be a list somewhere in the nasm manual.

Comment: Use `nasm -hf` to get a list of available formats. `elf32` or `elf64` would be my first guesses.

Comment: I made it elf and gcc still cannot read it.

Comment: Try PECOFF, then.  And it would really help if you said what operating system you were using and what `gcc -v` prints.

Comment: I am using windows 7 (64 bit). I will try PECOFF.

Comment: How do I make nasm put out a pecoff?

Comment: `-f something`.  I really don't know beans about nasm, but this is the sort of thing that *should* be in its manual.

Comment: I looked in the nasm manual and it does not say how to make nasm put out a pecoff. It does say however, how to make a coff. I tried that and ld still will not accept it.

Comment: If I had gas, I could have just wrote my startup file in at&t syntax. Were can i get gas for windows?

Comment: You have (MinGW, I presume) gcc, so you have gas too.  Write the AT&T startup file and assemble it with `gcc -c` just like you would a C source file.

Comment: I wrote my startup file in AT&T syntax. I get no errors but when I try and run it, it still does not print anything. Are you sure that its .globl start and not .global start?

Comment: `.globl` and `.global` do exactly the same thing in GAS.  Your problem is likely to be elsewhere.  You do realize you're using a 10-year-old tutorial, yes?  Machine initialization on a modern x86 is not *that* different from 10 years ago but I could see it being *just different enough* to break something, such as the code to call the BIOS to print to the console.